# Is there such a thing as a cached grep?

Tags: caching, command-line, grep

Is there such a thing as a cached grep?  I'm thinking of something that caches the files for which grep was issued against so that it doesn't need to re-traverse the directory, or reload those files.  Does something like this already exist?

Comment: I don't believe so, but when you've accessed a file recently, it's likely to be in a fast flash memory cache on your hard drive (and I think some OSes even cache files in RAM), which should give you noticeably improved run times on everything but a first grep.

Comment: Well I think @XavierHolt answered my questions.  I meant the portion "does something like this already exist" to mean -- is there a way to get `grep` to cache.  I am aware of Lucene, but AFAIK you can't really run a regex against the store found in Lucene, while `grep` actually takes regexes.  Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: If you're just interested in the new content in the same files, look at the File::Tail perl module. It is something like `tail -f file | grep xyz` in shell.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really need is a *pipeline.* Grep handles this use case well by allowing you to re-filter previously filtered results by accepting data on standard input.

For example:

```
# Search for "bar" in lines that have "foo."
grep foo * | grep bar

# Search for "baz" in lines that don't have "quux."
grep -v quux * | grep baz
```